# is there any default class to check parameter, if exist need to remove it from url in java?

Tags: java, url

Is there any default class to check parameter, if exists need to remove it from url 
eg.: `url=www.google.com?&id=1` need to check this `id`, if exists need to remove it , any methods available in java?

Comment: Remove it from where? And in what context is this? Servlets? `java.net.URL`?.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need to remove the query parameters

Try the following code:

```
import java.net.*;

public static removeQueryParameters(String url)
{
try 
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/test.do/?id=1");

        URL urlNew = new URL(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(), url.getPath());
    }
    catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please note that your URL is malformed ... it is missing protocol "http://google.com/?&id=1"

Comment: this is from memory ... please note that you may need to add few more verification like port etc and test this function well ... hopefully this will be a good starting point